# Wordpress плагин. Нужно сделать всегда включенным

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, плагин

На сайте wp есть плагин https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/ Как можно сделать этот плагин обязательным, чтобы его нельзя было выключить клиентам из админки? Знаю, что есть такой вид плагинов, называется must use плагины. подскажите, можно ли данный плагин сделать таковым? Спасибо

Comment: См https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/ Но qtranslate-x  давно умер и я бы рекомендовал заменить его на актуальный аналог.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашелся

```
function run_activate_plugins($plugins = []) {
    if (!empty($plugins)) {
        $activate_plugins = get_option('active_plugins');
        foreach ($plugins as $plugin) {
            $plugin = trim(plugin_basename(trim($plugin)));
            if (!in_array($plugin, $activate_plugins)) {
                $activate_plugins[] = $plugin;
                sort($activate_plugins);
                do_action('activate_plugin', $plugin);
                update_option('active_plugins', $activate_plugins);
                do_action('activate_'.$plugin);
                do_action('activated_plugin', $plugin);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
run_activate_plugins(['qtranslate-x/qtranslate.php']);
```